How to recognize a list of elements using core NLP
I am working with core NLP in java and I am a beginner with that. So I would like to know how can I recognize a list of elements related to an action. I see could use POS tags but I don't know if there is a better option for that.
Example:"all cases sorted by name asc, description, date desc."
Sort = [name:asc, description:no-order, date:desc].
